# Generating unique events by spark streaming

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

### General description

I have spark job that process kafka stream and as result should generate **unique** events and push them to kafka topic

### Kafka stream details:

each event in kafka stream: user_id -> user_status. Need to generate event when status changed.

for example: 
stream (1, status_1), (1, status_1), (1, status_2), (1, status_2) should generate only 2 event -> (1, status_1), (1, status_2)

### Solutions

1. use updateStateByKey to generate event (and send it) if status was changed.

Cons: if one of the workers fails, during restarting it can reprocess the same dstream and generate duplication event

2. use updateStateByKey to mark event to be send and then run forEach in rdd to check whether event should be send or not.

Cons: implementation is more difficult/unreadable than with updateStateByKey

3. new mapWithState([SPARK-2629](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-2629)) (don't try, as still using old version of spark). Does this method has the same behavior as updateStateByKey during failover?

---

Is there any standard approach for this type of problem in spark streaming?